# echo php foreach loop result by 3 different row data

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have a foreach loop and my code looks this is:

```
$count =  count($testimonial)/3;
for ($i = 1;$i <= $count;$i++){
    echo '<p>Title</p>';
    foreach ($testimonial as $data){
    echo $data->testimonial_title.'<br>';
   }
}
```

This is the result:

Title

aligned media one
aligned media one
aligned media one
Middle aligned media
Middle aligned media
Middle aligned media
media
media
media

Title

aligned media one
aligned media one
aligned media one
Middle aligned media
Middle aligned media
Middle aligned media
media
media
media

Title

aligned media one
aligned media one
aligned media one
Middle aligned media
Middle aligned media
Middle aligned media
media
media
media

But i want something like this :

Title

aligned media one
aligned media one
aligned media one

Title

Middle aligned media
Middle aligned media
Middle aligned media

Title

media
media
media

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: what do you want to do with it ? if you want to print each item single time you should use a single loop ... for-each and remove the for ($i = 1;$i <= $count;$i++){ loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use count variable and increment it inside for loop. When the count is rounded to 3, print desired text:

```
$count = 0;

foreach ($testimonial as $data){
    if(!($count++ % 3))
        echo '<p>Title</p>';
    echo $data->testimonial_title.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just swipe your for loops like that:

```
$count =  count($testimonial)/3;

foreach ($testimonial as $data) {

   echo '<p>Title</p>';

   for ($i = 1;$i <= $count;$i++){ 
      echo $data->testimonial_title.'<br>';
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it setting previous title and comparing with current like below

```
$prev_title ='';  
foreach ($testimonial as $data){
   if($prev_title!=$data->testimonial_title)
   {
       echo 'Title<br/>';
   }
   echo $data->testimonial_title.'<br>';
   // setting current title to previous so that we can check it against next row
   $prev_title =$data->testimonial_title;
}
```

This will work for any number of rows

Comment: could you please accept my answer as correct answer... it will increase you reputations to ...

Answer (score 0):

```
$query=mysql_query(select*from [table_name] where [condition]");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$array_query=array();
$row1=$row['column_name'];
array_push($array_query,$row1);
}
foreach ($array_query As $i)
{
echo $i;
echo "br";
}
}
```